# Branch point of the given function

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts, branch-points

> Prove or disprove that $0$ is a branch point of $f(z)=\frac{e^{\sqrt{z}}-e^{\sqrt{-z}}}{sin{\sqrt{z}}}$

can I consider $z=\epsilon e^{i\theta}$ (points on a small circle centered at $0$) to determine branch points? what is the general way of looking for branch points and branch cuts?

Comment: Is the negative sign supposed to be inside the square root?

Comment: yes @RandomVariable it is given like that.

Comment: Yes, you can take a small circle and you can do the calculation for one branch. Take $\sqrt z$ to be the principal value and the branch of $f$ to be $(e^{\sqrt z} - e^{i \sqrt z})/\sin \sqrt z$, then this branch is analytic in a small neighborhood of $0$ minus the ray $(-\infty, 0]$. Show that $f(e^{(\pi - 0) i} \epsilon) - f(e^{(-\pi + 0) i} \epsilon) \neq 0$ for any small $\epsilon > 0$ (directly or by expanding into series in powers of $\sqrt z$). This proves that $0$ is a branch point. (The converse is not true, one of the branches may be analytic in a neighborhood of a branch point.)